# Adding the TraceId from Spring Cloud Sleuth to API Gateway filters

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have an API Gateway and one microservice. When the microservice is called from the Api gateway, both of them are supposed to get the same TraceID but my microservice has a completely new TraceID and I don't know where that is generated.

API Gateway Logs

```
2021-06-22 11:00:13.446 INFO [gateway, 3ad39a60c4ac0e95, 3ad39a60c4ac0e95] 776 [ctor-http-nio-2] c.m.c.u.config.APIRoutes Locator : Routes are
```

Microservice Logs

```
2021-06-22 11:00:34.285 INFO [service1, 2a758b1cb504ca75,62e0509ed861a50f, true] 556 [nio-8000-exec-5] c.m.c.u.service.MasterReport Service: Fetching latest business date
```

In order to fix this, I thought adding the TraceID of the api gateway to a HTTP header and adding this header into a custom API gateway filter and adding this filter to the API gateway would fix the problem. But I do not know for sure whether this is the right approach to solve my problem and even if it is, I do not know how to do this. Any code snippets or examples would be really helpful.

Please let me know whether the approach that I have is right or not and if there